# How can I match a pointer to a null object?

Tags: clang-static-analyzer

I'd like to match on all the ways a particular argument to a function can be null.  Right now I'm using

```
hasArgument(
        3,
        anyOf(
            cxxNullPtrLiteralExpr()
            ,integerLiteral() // Technically this would alert on a constant pointer; but that's madness
        )
    )
```

However this doesn't match the following code:

```
void* nullObj = nullptr;
function(nullptr, false, false, nullObj);
```

Is it possible/easy to track this and match it? Right now I have a very simpler matcher but I guess this type of analysis requires considerably more logic?

Comment: You need to accept it with any format or only nullpointer

Comment: Check this link. I hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/20405891/8339685

Comment: I don't quite understand the question

Comment: Have you already tried [EvaluateAsInt](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Expr.html#a0f6e749cb5925e01a5f08377f1d95d0a) to see if arg 3 can be deduced to have value 0?

Answer (score 1):

### High-level answer

You can't just "match" an expression whose value is NULL.  AST matching can only inspect the syntax of the argument, so if the argument is not a literal, you don't know if it might be NULL.

Instead, you need to use a *flow-sensitive checker* that queries the Clang SA constraint engine.  The constraint engine tracks values as they flow through the program.

The core of such a checker looks like this:

```
bool NullArgChecker::evalCall(const CallExpr *CE, CheckerContext &C) const {
  ProgramStateRef state = C.getState();
  auto SVal = C.getSVal(CE->getArg(0)).getAs<DefinedOrUnknownSVal>();
  if (SVal) {
    ConditionTruthVal Nullness = state->isNull(*SVal);
    if (Nullness.isConstrainedTrue()) {
```

Given a call expression `CE`, we get its first argument, then query the `CheckerContext` for the symbolic value `SVal` associated with the first argument.  We then ask if that value is known to be NULL.

### Complete example

Here is a complete example checker that reports a warning every time it sees a value known to be NULL being passed as the first argument of any function.

NullArgChecker.cpp:

```
// NullArgChecker.cpp
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665383/how-can-i-match-a-pointer-to-a-null-object

#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/BuiltinCheckerRegistration.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/BugReporter/BugType.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/Checker.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/CheckerManager.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/CheckerContext.h"

using namespace clang;
using namespace ento;

namespace {

class NullArgChecker : public Checker< eval::Call > {
  mutable std::unique_ptr<BuiltinBug> BT_nullarg;

public:
  NullArgChecker() {}
  bool evalCall(const CallExpr *CE, CheckerContext &C) const;
};

} // end anonymous namespace


bool NullArgChecker::evalCall(const CallExpr *CE, CheckerContext &C) const {
  ProgramStateRef state = C.getState();
  auto SVal = C.getSVal(CE->getArg(0)).getAs<DefinedOrUnknownSVal>();
  if (SVal) {
    // This is the core of this example checker: we query the constraint
    // engine to see if the symbolic value associated with the first
    // argument is known to be NULL along the current path.
    ConditionTruthVal Nullness = state->isNull(*SVal);
    if (Nullness.isConstrainedTrue()) {
      // Create a warning for this condition.
      ExplodedNode *N = C.generateErrorNode();
      if (N) {
        if (!BT_nullarg) {
          BT_nullarg.reset(new BuiltinBug(
              this, "Null Argument", "The first argument is NULL."));
        }
        C.emitReport(llvm::make_unique<BugReport>(
          *BT_nullarg, BT_nullarg->getDescription(), N));
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

void ento::registerNullArgChecker(CheckerManager &mgr) {
  mgr.registerChecker<NullArgChecker>();
}

bool ento::shouldRegisterNullArgChecker(const LangOptions &LO) {
  return true;
}
```

Changes to other files to hook this in:

```
--- a/clang/include/clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/Checkers.td
+++ b/clang/include/clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/Checkers.td
@@ -148,6 +148,10 @@ def NonnullGlobalConstantsChecker: Checker<"NonnilStringCon
stants">,

 let ParentPackage = CoreAlpha in {

+def NullArgChecker : Checker<"NullArg">,
+  HelpText<"Check for passing a NULL argument">,
+  Documentation<NotDocumented>;
+
 def BoolAssignmentChecker : Checker<"BoolAssignment">,
   HelpText<"Warn about assigning non-{0,1} values to Boolean variables">,
   Documentation<HasAlphaDocumentation>;
--- a/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -62,6 +62,7 @@ add_clang_library(clangStaticAnalyzerCheckers
   NonNullParamChecker.cpp
   NonnullGlobalConstantsChecker.cpp
   NullabilityChecker.cpp
+  NullArgChecker.cpp
   NumberObjectConversionChecker.cpp
   ObjCAtSyncChecker.cpp
   ObjCAutoreleaseWriteChecker.cpp
```

Example input to test it on:

```
// nullargpp.cpp
// Testing NullArg checker with C++.

#include <stddef.h>          // NULL

void somefunc(int*);

void nullarg1()
{
  somefunc(NULL);            // reported
  somefunc(0);               // reported
  somefunc(nullptr);         // reported
}

void nullarg2()
{
  int *p = 0;
  somefunc(p);               // reported
}

void nullarg3(int *p)
{
  if (p) {
    somefunc(p);             // not reported
  }
  else {
    somefunc(p);             // reported
  }
}

void not_nullarg(int *p)
{
  somefunc(p);               // not reported
}
```

Example run:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -E -o nullargpp.ii nullargpp.cpp
$ ~/bld/llvm-project/build/bin/clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=alpha.core.NullArg nullargpp.ii
nullargpp.cpp:10:3: warning: The first argument is NULL
  somefunc(
  ^~~~~~~~~
nullargpp.cpp:11:3: warning: The first argument is NULL
  somefunc(0);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
nullargpp.cpp:12:3: warning: The first argument is NULL
  somefunc(nullptr);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
nullargpp.cpp:18:3: warning: The first argument is NULL
  somefunc(p);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
nullargpp.cpp:27:5: warning: The first argument is NULL
    somefunc(p);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
5 warnings generated.
```

For maximum specificity, the above changes were made to llvm-project commit 05efe0fdc4 (March 2019), running on Linux, but should work with any Clang v9.